# Is it worth it to upgrade a solar system to get power from partially obstructed panels?

Tags: solar-panels, solar

So I did a 7K solar system in 2009. A year or two later I was reading about a new converter that removed the penalty for partially obstructed panels. In other words, if one of the 4 panels in a row is in shade, you still get some power generated.

Has anyone done a retrofit on an existing system to add one of these or does it not make any sense? If you have to replace the inverter, probably is not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are hearing about are called "micro-inverters". Instead of one large inverter, you have separate, small inverters, one on each panel. I believe you can get them both sepatate and already integrated into panels.

This would require rewiring your PV system, removing the old inverter and installing micros at each panel. as you say, probably not cost effective.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I might consider moving the array that does get partially obstructed and replace it with micros.